# Google Analytics on an Intranet - What constituers a Fully Qualified Domain Name?

Tags: google-analytics, intranet

We want to use Google Analytics on our intranet. It currently lives at `http://intranet`, which obviously won't work because Google Analytics requires an [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).

It's also available at `http://intranet.companyname.dom/` but I'm unable to add a property using that address, either. So what exactly are the requirements? Does it need to be a "proper" web address, e.g. `intranet.companyname.com` (albeit only visible internally)?

(Just to cover it off, we're OK with the privacy/security/etc implications of using a 3rd party analytics system on our intranet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google says the intranet must be accessible by a fully qualified domain name. So your `.dom` should be `.com` or any other TLD

> In order for Google Analytics to generate reports for your corporate
>   intranet usage, your corporate network must be able to reach the
>   Google Analytics JavaScript file (analytics.js). Try loading the file
>   in your browser using one of the following links:
>
> http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
>   https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
>
> If you can reach one of these URLs from your internal network, you can
>   use Google Analytics to collect data from your intranet. Your intranet
>   must also be accessible through a fully qualified domain name such as
>   http://intranet.example.com. The Google Analytics JavaScript won't
>   work if your intranet can only be accessed using a domain name that
>   isn't fully qualified, such as `http://intranet`.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009688?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google *wants* you to enter a FQDN but it's not a strict requirement, it mostly determines how the GA cookies are created in the client browser.

If your Intranet uses server names or a pseudo TLD (like .local), it's fine.